# aChartEngine: underlying series not shown when using multiple colors to paint area below series

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm creating a line chart with multiple series using aChartEngine library. 
I have modified the code in XYChartBuilder.java to create a sample and test if i can fill the area under each series with a specific color. I have an issue when trying to fill with a different color the area below each series. At the areas where the series overlap, the lines of the underlying series are not shown.

Following is the code i have used to add the series and data on the graph

```
    public void addSeries(int id) {

    String seriesTitle = "Series " + (mDataset.getSeriesCount() + 1);

    // create a new series of data
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries(seriesTitle);
    mDataset.addSeries(series);
    mCurrentSeries = series;

    // create a new renderer for the new series
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    // set some renderer properties
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValuesDistance(10);
    renderer.setLineWidth(2);

    if (id == 1) {

        FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BELOW);
        fill.setColor(Color.BLUE);     
        renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);

        renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);

    }

    if (id == 2) {

        FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BELOW);
        fill.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);

        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    }


    if (id == 3) {

        FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BELOW);
        fill.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        renderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);

        renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    }


    mCurrentRenderer = renderer;
    mChartView.repaint();

} 

    public void addData(double x, double y) {

    // add a new data point to the current series
    mCurrentSeries.add(x, y);

    // repaint the chart such as the newly added point to be visible
    mChartView.repaint();

}
```

When I need to create the series i call

```
    addSeries(1);
    addData(0, 0);
    addData(2, 3);
    addData(4, 0);

    addSeries(2);
    addData(2, 0);
    addData(6, 3);
    addData(8, 0);

    addSeries(3);
    addData(6, 0);
    addData(9, 3);
    addData(11, 0);
```

In the case where I specify in the addSeries function the FillOutsideLine object but do not set the color I get the expected behavior I want. However,the areas under each series are drawn with the same color (blue - it seems to be the default).

Unfortunately I'm new and my reputation is still low, thus I cannot upload any images.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Lupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem so I'm listing it in case someone else is having the same issue. The problem occurred as I used a solid color to paint the area under the series. I tested it with a semi-transparent color and the problem is now solved.

Example:

```
    fill.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5500FF66"));
```

L.